# How to create TextField with spannable text in Jetpack compose

Tags: transformation, spannable, jetpack

How to create TextField with spannable text where every word is wrapped in separate spannable.
Do I need to use VisualTransformation?
Must be something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberMaterial3Colors
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp

@Composable
fun SpannableTextField(text: String) {
    val spannableText = createSpannableText(text)
    
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = TextFieldValue(text = spannableText),
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(fontSize = 16.sp),
            onValueChange = {},
            singleLine = true
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun createSpannableText(text: String): AnnotatedString {
    val words = text.split(" ")

    return AnnotatedString.Builder().apply {
        words.forEachIndexed { index, word ->
            val start = length
            val end = start + word.length

            addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    color = getRandomColor(),
                    fontSize = 16.sp
                ),
                start = start,
                end = end
            )

            append(word)

            if (index < words.size - 1) append(" ")
        }
    }.toAnnotatedString()
}

private fun getColor(): Color {
    // You can create logic for generating random color here.
    return Color.Red
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun SpannableTextFieldPreview() {
    SpannableTextField(text = "transformation spannable jetpack")
}
```

Comment: but if I want to do it dynamic, then user writing and create spannable after space?

Comment: Ah well then I am not sure how you'd implement it while writing. You might be able to do an input below or above the spannable and on submit of the input, add a new spannable text after the last space?

Comment: then user writing in field, after user click on space, the word before must be changed to spannable text. May be it could be done with VisualTransformation?

Comment: and additionally, your example creates one spannable with all text